Different method leads to different result - What is wrong?
In the reference below, the following simple problem is presented:
Bank of Ireland offered a 9 month fixed term reward account paying 2.55% on maturity, for new funds from €10,000 to €500,000. (That is, you got your money back in 9 months, along with 2.55% interest.) Confirm that this was an EAR of 3.41%.
I used the following calculation instead of the presented calculation in the reference as follows:
if for 9 months one gets 2.55% then for 12 months, one gets 2.55%/(12/9)=3.40 NOT 3.41.
I expected this to work exactly at least for 2 significant digits, since there is NO COMPOUNDING. I assume that using the formula for EAR would give 3.41!
Could someone explain why I get 3.40 where the correct answer is 3.41?
Reference of this problem

taking the poor explanation from the same document:

For every euro you invested, you got back €1.0255 in 3/4 of a year’s
time. At 3.41%, the present value of this return is
€1.0255/(1.0341^0.75) =  €1

which is as it should be.
Alternatively, just confirm that
€1.0341 ^ 3/4 = €1.0255 , or that €1.0255^ 4/3  = 1.0341


The last part of the last  equation is the only one you need.

I expected this to work exactly at least for 2 significant digits,
since there is NO COMPOUNDING. I assume that using the formula for EAR
would give 3.41!

But there is compounding. After 9 months the money in your account went from 1 to 1.0255 so that if they offered that same deal again, you would get a little more interest because you are getting interest on the original interest.
I didn't like the answer from the document because the first two times they worked the problem they were trying to prove that 3.41 was the answer, not tell you how to calculate it.

Thank you for your answer. The compounding effect is not mentioned explicitly.

Compounding period is the same as the investment period. Hence no compounding took place --> The expected result is to be the same as simple interest without compounding...
